# Transformation of text file into an xml using datapower

Tags: xslt, text, ibm-datapower

I want to transfer a non-xml text file delimited by '|' characters into an xml using Datapower.

```
Following is file  (sample1)
```

10|20003|24/23/25|23890

Now i have to break this into the following XML

```
 <ResponseType>
        <ResCode>10</ResCode>
        <Id>20003</Id>
         <SoftCode>24/23/25</SoftCode>
        <StatusCode>23890</StatusCode>
  </ResponseType>
```

What I did was following--

1>Create a Transform action in the service that will be receiving non-XML requests.

2>Select "Use XSLT specified in this action on a non-XML message" to specify that this is a Binary Transform.

3>Upload the following stylesheet as the Processing Control File.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
    version="1.0">

    <dp:input-mapping href="sample1.ffd" type="ffd"/>


    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="ResponseType"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="str:tokenize">
     <xsl:with-param name="string" select="string" />

    </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="str:tokenize">
<xsl:with-param name="string" select="">

    str:tokenize('string', '|')
</xsl:with param>
</xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

and here is my sample1.ffd(which I have uploaded in my local://  directory in Datapower

```
<File name="ResponseType">
<!-- capture all data into this tag -->
<Field name="ResCode/Id/SoftCode/StatusCode" />
</File>
```

But I am not getting desired output , I think my xslt is quite wrong
What can I do do  to get desired output?

Comment: Hmm, XSLT is intended for XML -> something (usually other XML) transformations. AFAIK an XML (or at least equivalent datatype) could be the only data source for XSLT.

Comment: Your XSLT has some problems: "str" is an undefined namespace and the use of `xsl:with-param` at `xsl:template` should probably be `xsl:param`.

Comment: In IBM DataPower you have a transformer called FFD (Contivo) you can use. DataPower needs to understand the incoming data is not XML so a regular XSLT won't work unfortunately... See my answer for use of FFD below.

Although you should probably look into WebSphere Transformation Extender (WTX) for binary (=non-xml) transforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how IBM Datapower might solve this problem, but for XSLT, you would at least wrap your input in a XML element:

```
<Whatever>
10|20003|24/23/25|23890
</Whatever>
```

And then you could go on with a transformation like follows. The hard part is splitting your text input. In XSLT 1.0, there is no function available for that, so you need a recursive template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="msxml">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="tokenized">
      <items>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="//text()" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </items>
    </xsl:variable>
    <ResponseType>
      <ResCode>
        <xsl:copy-of select="msxml:node-set($tokenized)/items/item[1]/text()" />
      </ResCode>
      <Id>
        <xsl:copy-of select="msxml:node-set($tokenized)/items/item[2]/text()" />
      </Id>
      <SoftCode>
        <xsl:copy-of select="msxml:node-set($tokenized)/items/item[3]/text()" />
      </SoftCode>
      <StatusCode>
        <xsl:copy-of select="msxml:node-set($tokenized)/items/item[4]/text()" />
      </StatusCode>
    </ResponseType>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <xsl:variable name="item" select="normalize-space( substring-before( concat( $string, '|'), '|'))" />
    <xsl:if test="$item">
      <item>
        <xsl:value-of select="$item" />
      </item>
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,'|')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In IBM DataPower you have a transformer called FFD (Contivo) you can use. DataPower needs to understand the incoming data is not XML so a regular XSLT won't work unfortunately... See my answer for use of FFD below.

Answer (score 2):

In DataPower using FFD the following should work:

1) Add the FFD file (below one of my old education samples):

```
<File name="CSVFILE">
    <Group name="CSVLine" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" delim="\n">
        <Field name="id"/>
        <Field name="fname" delim=","/>
        <Field name="lname" delim=","/>
        <Field name="title" delim=","/>
        <Field name="dept" delim=","/>
        <Field name="org"/>
    </Group>
</File>
```

2) Add the XSLT (this one simply copies the FFD transformed XML to output):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
                version="1.0">

    <dp:input-mapping href="CSVFILE.FFD" type="ffd"/>

    <!-- This stylesheet copies the input to the output -->
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:copy-of select="." />

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

3) Send a message:

```
1,Anders,Wasen,B2B Architect,DataPower Dev,Enfo Zystems
2,Jean-Luc,Piccard,Captain,USS Enterprise,Star Fleet
```

4) This will result in the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CSVFILE>
 <CSVLine>
  <id>1</id>
  <fname>Anders</fname>
  <lname>Wasen</lname>
  <title>B2B Architect</title>
  <dept>DataPower Dev,Enfo Zystems</dept>
  <org/>
 </CSVLine>
 <CSVLine>
  <id>2</id>
  <fname>Jean-Luc</fname>
  <lname>Piccard</lname>
  <title>Captain</title>
  <dept>USS Enterprise,Star Fleet</dept>
  <org/>
 </CSVLine>
</CSVFILE>
```

Make sure that you change the XSLT Transform action into "Transform Binary" and set Request Type to "non-xml", else it will not work!

Hope this will help you! :)